# What might cause a *.jar file to run normally and then suddenly become slow?

Tags: java, performance, jar, timer

I made a simple action game using a Timer. The game speed, the player's ship speed and the missiles' speeds are final int variables that never change.

I built a jar file. It ran fine every time, literally hundreds of times in a row, whether running the jar or inside JavaBeans. Then it suddenly became consistently slow whether running the jar or inside JavaBeans.

This was true after rebooting and even after trying it on another pc with a fresh install of the jdk. I rebuilt the jar on my pc and it was normal speed again but then that build too got slow.

I reinstalled the jdk and it is working OK at the moment but I can't say for how long. My question, before I upload the code, is: what external cause like a faulty jdk could be to blame ? I'm a beginning programmer and cannot 100% say that my code isn't somehow to blame, but then why would the jar work fine for so long ?

Besides the main files, there are wav and png files and a text file to hold the high score. The high score file is the only thing that changes between executions, but it hasn't been changed since long before the problem started.

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 1
Java: 1.8.0_121; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.121-b13
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_121-b13
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_CA (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\Rowan\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2
Cache directory: C:\Users\Rowan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2
```

Comment: How are you building the jar? Are you using the  "Extract required libraries into generated file"  option?

Comment: Sounds like a performance issue. Degrading performance of a Java application can usually be due to memory management problems. Try increasing the verbosity of the JVM GC and see if the GC is behaving well.

Comment: @SamYuyitung I don't know where that option is. However, I can tell you the same issue existed inside JavaBeans' Run and Debug modes.

Comment: @NickCaballero I will learn what is meant about the verbosity of garbage collection, although my speed issue is inconsistent with gc hiccups. The game doesn't stutter or lag, or start normal and then slow down, it simply runs at a single consistent speed that is about half what it should.

Comment: 'JavaBeans'? Do you mean *NetBeans?*

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant NetBeans.

Comment: Try profiling your jar via applications like Visual VM. May be many threads are blocked waiting for a single resource, Check for synchronous blocks in your code. Also check for GC pause times. Personally I feel it's very unlikely that it was JDK problem.